# error when logging to application

Tags: out-of-memory, permgen

when logging to application i have error
tomcat 7 in win7 with java options

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1536m 
-Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

in startup.bat i have error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at com.documentum.thirdparty.javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:68)
        at com.documentum.thirdparty.javassist.CtNewClass.<init>(CtNewClass.java:38)
        at com.documentum.thirdparty.javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:621)
        at com.documentum.thirdparty.javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:605)
        at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.reflection.proxy.ProxyClassGenerator.newClass(ProxyClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.reflection.proxy.ProxyClassGenerator.makeProxyByteCode(ProxyClassGenerator.java:54)
        at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.reflection.proxy.ProxyClassLoader.makeProxyClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:93)
        at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.reflection.proxy.ProxyClassLoader.loadProxyClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:47)
        at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.reflection.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:74)
        at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.reflection.proxy.ProxyFactory.makeDoubleProxy(ProxyFactory.java:53)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.compoundclass.PObjectProxyFactory.newProxyInstance(PObjectProxyFactory.java:27)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.compoundclass.PObjectProxyFactory.newProxyInstance(PObjectProxyFactory.java:18)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.compoundclass.DynamicProxyMgr.newProxy(DynamicProxyMgr.java:44)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PObjectFactoryWithAspects.makeObject(PObjectFactoryWithAspects.java:52)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentObjectManager.getObjectFromServer(PersistentObjectManager.java:356)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentObjectManager.getObject(PersistentObjectManager.java:311)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.getObject(Session.java:834)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.getObjectByQualificationEx(Session.java:1015)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.getObjectByQualification(Session.java:993)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.util.DfModificationManager.doFetch(DfModificationManager.java:154)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.util.DfModificationManager.getChangeRecordObject(DfModificationManager.java:123)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.util.DfModificationManager.init(DfModificationManager.java:217)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.util.DfModificationManager.getInstance(DfModificationManager.java:36)
        at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.BofConsistencyChecker.makeConsistent(BofConsistencyChecker.java:35)
```

tried different options and still this error...

Answer (score 0):

You have -XX:PermSize=512m and -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

You might want to start with swapping the sizes, so that the max value is higher than the initial: -XX:PermSize=256m and -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: Then I think you should try JVisualVM and connect it to your running process to get a better view of the memory consumption. There is a guide on how to set it up here: http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/